# Should we post every question from the first phase of the site?

Tags: discussion

When the Mathematics Educators proposal was first suggested, we needed 40+ questions with a score of 10+. These 40 questions are agreed to be representative of what we want for the site; should we ask **all** of them? If not, why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If one of those questions represents an *actual* problem you are currently facing, then feel free to go ahead and flesh it out with the details and ask it. But those "example questions" were simply a means to establish the scope of this site, and don't *necessarily* represent real problems that need to be asked simply to seed this site with content.

[Your New Site: Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

Some of those questions are very basic, and none of them are fleshed out enough to comprise an *actual* problem that needs answering. I would suggest that that we shouldn’t be asking these type of sample questions, especially so early in the beta. To keep this site interesting, you will need a site where people are asking very interesting and challenging questions about problem they actually face.

Education is ripe with challenges that you face every day. In comparison, I think that most of the questions from Area 51 are going to look somewhat staged and force. It's not really going to help this site establish an interesting identity, and it's not really going to help prepare the site for opening day.

Comment: Since when do beta questions need to be actual problems that we are currently facing? I thought that we were explicitly supposed to post questions that we would expect to be helpful to other people because they contain typical problems that other people face. And no, that does not mean that I want to ask the area51 questions, but your restriction seems much too strong. We do not really need to wait for the next exam season to discuss grading.

Comment: @user11235: I think it's a good thing if the questions are real questions, since the beta is already a real and live version of our SE site. If you have an actual question about grading, no one is stopping you to post it.